# elastic query update in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to update multiple documents which match a query using spring-elastic but when i use below snippet in my spring code i am getting exception<1.1>

```
UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder updateRequest =  UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client);
```

1.1

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/support/ActiveShardCount
    at org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.AbstractBulkByScrollRequest.<init>(AbstractBulkByScrollRequest.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.AbstractBulkIndexByScrollRequest.<init>(AbstractBulkIndexByScrollRequest.java:52)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.UpdateByQueryRequest.<init>(UpdateByQueryRequest.java:51)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.UpdateByQueryRequest.<init>(UpdateByQueryRequest.java:47)
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>reindex</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Note: i am using elastic 2.4.1

Please let me know how to achieve "query Update", any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Add this in your pom `<elasticsearch.version>2.4.1</elasticsearch.version>`

Comment: @alkis I included the snippet and tried , still the exception persists any idea what i could be missing.

Comment: Have you included the elasticsearch client?

Comment: Yes, Please find the below config

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: why are you using a different version?

Comment: sry that is a typo, tried  with 2.4.1, still error persists